# How to find out which account is changing the site collection locks and quotas

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Folks,

Need your valuable suggestion on my Sharepoint 2010 site quotas and lock issue.
Not sure how the site collection changing from "No Lock" status to "Read Only", **How to audit or find out.**
checked so far: No local disk Space Issue, Quota limit not full, SQL db Server space is enough, backups successfully running but still it's changing to Read only, Nothing into the event logs & ULS Logs.

Find the info from IIS logs but which is recording the a/c name like who is reverting the changes(i.e.. Read Only to No Lock).. but i would like to track which a/c initially changing from No lock to Read only(which i cant find in ULS logs).
Appreciate your suggestions.

Thanks
Santosh

Answer (score 1):

you best bet is check the IIS Logs on the Server and check who is accessing this page: _admin/sitequota.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your info Sarwar...Find the info from IIS logs but which is recording the a/c name like who is reverting the changes(i.e.. Read Only to No Lock).. but i would like to track which a/c initially changing from No lock to Read only(which i cant find in ULS logs). Appreciate your suggestions...

Comment: @Santosh -- I think the idea is that from the IIS logs you could filter it down to a few possible users and then use best judgement from there.  You shouldn't have lots of different accounts accessing that page.